# How to set width to 100% for Listview part of SlidingPaneLayout

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-listview, slidingpanelayout

I have a [SlidingPaneLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/widget/SlidingPaneLayout.html) in which left pane is a Listview and the right pane is the detail view. The XML is below.

Problem is that - how do i make the width of the listview to cover the entire screen? As you can see below (red arrows), the current width doesnt go all the way to the right of the screen.

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/sliding_pane_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<!--
     The first child view becomes the left pane. When the combined
     desired width (expressed using android:layout_width) would
     not fit on-screen at once, the right pane is permitted to
     overlap the left. 
-->

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/ll_left_pane"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="0dp" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_pane"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<!--
     The second child becomes the right (content) pane. In this
     example, android:layout_weight is used to express that this
     pane should grow to consume leftover available space when the
     window is wide enough. This allows the content pane to
     responsively grow in width on larger screens while still
     requiring at least the minimum width expressed by
     android:layout_width.
-->


<!-- Framelayout to display Fragments -->

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frame_container_slidingpanedetailview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SlidingPaneLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list view in this case is bound to take fixed value hence change the width parameter of list view and put some very big value in width attribute  like 500dp or 1000dp.

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/left_pane"
        android:layout_width="500dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"


        android:layout_marginRight="0dp" />
```

Comment: ok that worked, but i wonder if i need to add any special code in java to detect screen width and set it above that, or a big value like 1000dp would take care of it or not. Thanks, will mark as answer.

Comment: You can find the screen width progrmatically . But i doubt that would reflect on screen as this setting has to be given to the slidingpanel before the view is created, that is why relative width values dont work here.

Answer (score 0):

use below attribute for listview in xml:

```
app:layout_widthPercent="100%"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got stuck in the same problem and then after lot of searching I got the following solution. Try this:

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Hope this helps.